# Incoming message Receiver and notify default system message app for Kitkat and above

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, message

Hi everyone I am developing a messaging app and follow all instruction from google blog [link here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

and it is working very fine .But i have a problem when my app is working as default messaging app i want to save message in my app db as well as device default message app db so that when device message app turns to default all messages can be seen there too.

Point is how i can notify default messaging app to save message when i am using my app as default app.

please help! sorry for bad english

**#Update 1**
for saving in default db i am using following code

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;
private String msg_from;
//private MessageDataBaseAdapter messageDataBaseAdapter;
private String msgBody;
public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";
public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";

public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String PERSON = "person";
public static final String DATE = "date";
public static final String READ = "read";
public static final String STATUS = "status";
public static final String TYPE = "type";
public static final String BODY = "body";
public static final String SEEN = "seen";

public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2;

public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ = 0;
public static final int MESSAGE_IS_READ = 1;

public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN = 0;
public static final int MESSAGE_IS_SEEN = 1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER")) {
        HideSMSToast.showShortToast("Your Message Hasbeen received");

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); // ---get the SMS message passed
        // Get ContentResolver object for pushing encrypted SMS to incoming folder
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();                             // in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                // String strMessageFrom =
                // bundle.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    //Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    // System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());
                    // SCSLToast.showShortToast(c.getTime().toString());
                    //SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    //      "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                    //String formattedDate = date.format(c.getTime());

                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();                     
                    //Db operation
                     saveSmsDataToDefaulDB( contentResolver, msgs[i] );
                }
                ///
                } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                //messageDataBaseAdapter.close();
            }
        }

    }
}

private void saveSmsDataToDefaulDB( ContentResolver contentResolver, SmsMessage sms )
 {
     // Create SMS row
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put( ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress());
     values.put( DATE, sms.getTimestampMillis());
     values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ);
     values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus());
     values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX);
     values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN);        
     contentResolver.insert( Uri.parse(SMS_URI), values);
     HideSMSToast.showShortToast("Content written in default message app db");
 }}
```

and I got the message in defaul system messagenig app but address i got correctelly and no other data..
please tell me how to store data in default messaging db

Here is the screen shots how i got message in system default sms app when i make my app as default app
[image]

**# Update 2**
thanks guys for support I have resolve it it was silly mistake I had done .I am updating my code as following

```
private void saveSmsDataToDefaulDB( ContentResolver contentResolver, SmsMessage sms )
 {
     // Create SMS row
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put( ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress());
     values.put( DATE, sms.getTimestampMillis());
     values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ);
     values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus());
     values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX);
     values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN);
     values.put(BODY, sms.getMessageBody());
     contentResolver.insert( Uri.parse(SMS_URI), values);
    // HideSMSToast.showShortToast("Content written in default message app db");
 }
```

Comment: This link may be helpful to you: https://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/

Comment: @RajanBhavsar thanks for the comment but this is not what i want I have done saving in my app db .